# How can I type ティ `ti` (small ィ) in Japanese on OSX?

Tags: macos, language, japanese

I have been typing in Japanese for a while now but I cannot figure out how to type ティ (small ィ, not a big one イ).

How does one do this using the Katakana input method of OSX?

Comment: ティ is "ti", not "tei"

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Just type `texi` in Katakana mode. Generally, prefixing `x` will generate the small variant character (useful if you need to generate ゅ, ょ or っ in isolation).

Comment: li (L and I) do the same thing too. Prefixing any character with l also makes it small

Comment: This answer also applies to Windows 10, thanks (:

Answer (score 17):

The `x` prefix does generate the small variant, but what you probably want is `thi`.

Comment: +1 for the shortcut, but more generally, can you point to a resource somewhere that summarizes all shortcuts in the manner of `thi` instead of `texi` or `teli` ? Thanks.

Comment: On Linux, I found the complete list by clicking on the status icon that says **あ**, then Mozc Tool / Configuration Tool / **Romaji Table / Customize**. This opens a table with the full list of shortcuts. Maybe it's in a similar place in OS X and other systems.

Comment: Interesting, although I tried `thu` to get the same as with `texu` but instead got only hiragana てゅ and no katakana version is suggested.
And when typing `tyu` I get チュ

Answer (score 4):

Building off of Justin's answer, there's a few other special [kana input strings](http://www.textfugu.com/season-4/social-learning/9-4/) that I found online. This is not an exhaustive list.

> wi = ウィ/うぃ
>
> we = ウェ/うぇ
>
> va = ヴァ/ゔぁ
>
> vi = ヴィ/ゔぃ
>
> vu = ヴ/ゔ
>
> ve = ヴェ/ゔぇ
>
> vo = ヴォ/ヴぉ
>
> she = シェ/しぇ
>
> je = ジェ/じぇ
>
> fa = ファ/ふぁ
>
> fi = フィ/ふぃ
>
> fe = フェ/ふぇ
>
> fo = フォ/ふぉ
>
> che = チェ/ちぇ

Comment: Unfortunately _ti_  produces ち, not ティ. I would say that _chi_ producing ち is enough.

Comment: there's other romanizations where ti = chi. anyway, you can always produce little letters by typing x before the letter.

Comment: Agree, but it would be more natural to have ti = ティ, since it's the official romanization, and why have two different ways of inputting ち anyway?
If an option so counter-intuitive like using X hadn't been used, I guess less people would need to come and ask in places like this. The best UI is the one that works as most users expect it to.

Comment: Native Japanese speakers regularly use "ti" to mean ち.

Comment: Yes, but the typing system suggests katakana ティ as the first option when typing both `thi` and `texi`, so it guesses correctly that I'm trying to write katakana.  
Despite `ti` being an acceptable way to type hiragana ち, when I type `ti` ち is the first option, and the only katakana suggestion I get is チ, while ティ doesn't even show up in the list.

Comment: That sounds expected. Japanese speakers use ti to mean ち or チ. If you think it should be different I suggest you take it up with the devs who made the input method that you use, or you can design your own keyboard input method or a macro for your personal use.